# How to throw an object that slowly goes up and comes down normally like you would with a ball being slightly thrown into the air in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to throw an object into a bin with physics that look realistic but I don't understand how to. I have tried doing Rigidbody.AddForce() and many other things but that doesn't work. Please help me I am very confused.

Comment: You cant just addforce or its more like the result of it hitting a wall. You woukd need to consider how you throw it yourself and build up speed adding force till the object leaves the “hand”

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a realistic result, then `AddForce(Vector3)` is your only choice. You can play with changing the gravity force in physics setting, or try using different ForceModes in the overload of `AddForce(Vector3, ForceMode)` (some of them let you ignore mass if that would be of any help), but that's it for realistic options.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the only thing is that I have tried doing AddForce but this requires the rigid body component and my object will simply fall out of the world I'm in. I tried putting the velocity to 0 and still doesn't work. What angle and postition do I set the AddForce to?

Comment: Well, of course you can get around the Rigidbody thing. You can implement projection motion on your own basing on the formula. I've done it a couple of times previously and I can tell you that AddForce is going to work exactly the same way. I don't know your exact situation, but you can surround your world with Colliders to prevent your object falling out of it (it's gonna need a Collider too). Regarding the question - well, you have to figure out on your own what kind of a force vector you want to add to your object